# Outline on scale and filters on flipcards

Tags: html, css, frontend

I've been trying to implement some filter effects on flipcards that aren't hovered but I discovered these really annoying 0-1 px  "outlines" on sides that match the length of the side.

[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvqNu.png)

One of the combinations that trigger the issue is transform: scale + filter: blur.

Does anybody know what the problem might be and possibly how to get rid of it?

(Made it into button to simplify).

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card-item');
const thirdCard = cards[2];


function flipCard(){
    cards.forEach(card=>{
        if(card!==thirdCard){
            card.classList.toggle('blur');

        } else{
            card.classList.toggle('flip');
        }
    });
}
```

```css
h1, h2{
    margin: 0;
}

.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.card-list{
    width: 80%;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.card-list .card-item{
    height: 30vh;
    width: 30vw;

    margin: 10px;

    perspective: 1000px;
}

.card-list .card-item .card{
    position: relative;
    transition: 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.front, .back{
    position: absolute;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.front{
    background-color: blue;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    z-index: 1;
}

.back{
    background-color: red;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.btn{
    width: 100%;
    height: 10vh;
}

.card-item.flip .card{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card-item.blur .card{
    transform: scale(0.8);
    filter: blur(2px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="card-list">
            <div class="card-item">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="front">
                        <h1>FRONT</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <h2>BACK</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-item">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="front">
                        <h1>FRONT</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <h2>BACK</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-item">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="front">
                        <h1>FRONT</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <h2>BACK</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-item">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="front">
                        <h1>FRONT</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                        <h2>BACK</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>

    <button class="btn" onclick="flipCard()">Flip card 3</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how about removing perspective: 1000px ?

Comment: @emsliggy That's correct, this removes the black edges, you can post this as an answer.

Comment: @emsiiggy ok. But is it the only way? I really wanted to have that 3d effect on a flip

Comment: @Mirz these lines appear only in Google Chrome right? Firefox or Opera don't display it probably...

Comment: @Mirz you can always change scale(0.8) to scale(0.81) although it strange way...

Comment: @emsiiggy Well... In firefox it doesn't even show divs with both scale and filter on them. (Idk how changing scale could help).